# Write data from dictionary to a csv file in a specific format

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
dic = {"HM1": ['Jackson','Matt','M','Football'], "SM2":['Scott','Max','M']}
```

i need a code that "writes" these dictionary data to csv file in the form:

```
HM1,Jackson,Matt,M,Football
SM2,Scott,Max,M
```

i have a following code which doesn't work:

```
with open("file.csv", "w", newline="") as new_data:
    fieldnames = ['ID','Firstname','Lastname','Gender','Sports']
    data_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_data, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    for k in dic.keys():
        r = dic[k]
        data_writer.writerow({'ID':r[0],'Firstname':r[1],'Lastname':r[2],'Gender':r[3],'Sports':r[4]})
```

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't very descriptive, but I'm imagining it's due to `IndexError` since `r[4]` doesn't exist in your input?

Answer (score 1):

first, make sure that your list have  the same length,

if so you have to convert it to a dataframe and convert the dataframe to a csv file by using pandas module:
inatall it by using

```
pip install pandas
```

and import it like this :

```
import pandas as pd



df = pd.DataFrame({"HM1": ['Jackson','Matt','M','Football'], "SM2":['Scott','Max','M', '']})
df = df.T 
df.to_csv('path_to_file.csv', header=False)
```

**UPDATE** :
if your data lists  doesn't have the same length you can proceded like this :

```
data_dict= {"HM1": ['Jackson','Matt','M','Football'], "SM2":['Scott','Max','M']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[x for x in data_dict.values()], index= data_dict.keys())
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
df.to_csv('path_to_file.csv', header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

```
with open("file.csv", "w", newline="") as new_data:
    fieldnames = ['ID','Firstname','Lastname','Gender','Sports']
    data_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_data, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    data_writer.writeheader()
    for k,r in dic.items():        
        data_writer.writerow({fieldnames[i]: k if i == 0 else r[i-1] for i in range(len(r)+1)})
```

Some issues from your original code:

1.) You never wrote the "ID" column from the dictionary key.
2.) You could easily iterate over `dic.items()` which returns both key and item instead of using `r = dic[k]`.
3.) Your `r` is returning an `IndexError` because your second row is missing a value, so `r[4]` will raise an error with a list length of only 3.  This could be easily handled dynamically with a list comprehension instead.

Anyhow, the **output**:

> ```
> ID,Firstname,Lastname,Gender,Sports
> HM1,Jackson,Matt,M,Football
> SM2,Scott,Max,M,
> ```

I would recommend you handle the missing data from the lists somehow (like 'N/A') instead of just leaving the lists in uneven length.  The other answer's `pandas` solution is great, but if you are not comfortable with that module or installing external modules in general, this solution sticks with `csv` only.